# Migrating from npm to yarn when package.json has incorrect versions

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, yarnpkg

I recently started working on a pre-existing react-native project, and upon setup I encountered a lot of dependency and versioning errors. The versions on package.json are incorrect for our project, and it caused errors when I ran it until we finally decided to just copy the node_modules folder into my repository from another team member's working repo instead of using `npm install`.

We'd like to migrate the project to Yarn so that this doesn't continue to happen, but when I try to create a yarn.lock file using either `yarn install` or `yarn install --check-files`, I end up with wrong versions and a broken project. Is there any way to generate a yarn.lock file, and potentially a new package.json, based on the versions that are in the node_modules directory?

Comment: You can go into each package within the working `node_modules` dir, check the versions in each package.json file, then update the project's (main) package.json dependencies to that strict version. `"some_dep": "1.2.3"`

Comment: Is there any way that's not manual? That could take a super long time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try `npm init`?

It will ask you a few questions and generate the package.json with dependencies based on existing /node_modules.

Comment: I tried, but it didn't seem to work. That does seem like it would work though.

Comment: Is it? I just tried `npm init` with an existing /node_modules folder and the generated package.json able to list out the dependencies.

Comment: @StrugLife10 Which version of npm are you using now? It seems like you need npm >= [v3.3.0](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v3.3.0) to init with existing /node_modules.

Comment: I'm using 4.2.0